# A metric on T(G/H)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I want to know which isomorphism of vector bundles is the following?

[alt text http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_uGcgLiQvkI8/TAgpIivl6oI/AAAAAAAAAKk/DCg9iK2W3rA/s1600/Capture-52.png](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_uGcgLiQvkI8/TAgpIivl6oI/AAAAAAAAAKk/DCg9iK2W3rA/s1600/Capture-52.png)

where $G/H$ is the quotient of group $G$ by its subgroup $H$ and $T(G/H)$ is the tangent bundle, $G\times_H \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ is the bundle associated to the principal bundle $G\to G/H$ via the adjointe representation on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$

Comment: Pedro -- what exactly do you want to know about this isomorphism?

Comment: I want to know how it works... I mean a relation that expresses this isomorphism

Comment: Why is the question titled "a metric on T(G/H)"?  The isomorphism you mention has nothing to do with metrics.

Comment: Ah yes! because with this isomorphisme I can construct a metric on T(G/H) using the metric on g/h

Comment: By this do you mean perhaps that if you have an inner product on g/h which is invariant under the adjoint action of H, then it extends to a G-invariant metric on G/H?

Comment: Exactly         .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an obvious map $G\times\mathfrak g\to G\times_H\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$, and an isomorphism $TG\to G\times\mathfrak g$. On the other hand, the projection $G\to G/H$ gives a map $TG\to T(G/H)$. Now you can construct a map $T(G/H)\to G\times_H\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ as the composition $$T(G/H)\leftarrow TG\to G\times\mathfrak g\to G\times_H\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h.$$ Here the backwards arrow means "pick any preimage".

Comment: Interesting convention this backwards arrow, Mariano.

Comment: I just did not want to write too much :P I can trace the notation to the additive relations in MacLane's Homology

Comment: Nice!

Now I want to know if this is true

$G\times_H\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h \sim G/H \times (\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h)/Ad(H)$

Comment: That cannot be true for a number of reasons, the most basic perhaps is the following. The left-hand side is a homogeneous vector bundle over $G/H$, whereas the right-hand side (assuming you mean what I understand by your notation) is not even a manifold in general, since the orbit structure of the vector space $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ under the adjoint action of $H$ can be quite complicated.